# Anyway to resume a download on uGet?

Tags: download-manager, resume, uget

I was trying to download windows 7 ISO file with uGet, and for some reason i got disconnected at 96 percent, and as i'm trying to resume or force start it it does not resume, is there any fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't force a resume if a server doesn't allow a resume. uGet will automatically try to resume if it can but if it fails to do so it is likely because the server doesn't allow it to be done. Sadly, I'd be surprised if Microsoft allowed resumes.

Comment: I remember resuming downloads from IDM once it failed and could not resume, thats why i asked for someway to do the same with uGet. It's not necessary atm.

Comment: It is possible to do so in some cases and most of the time it is automatically initiated via the "Runnable" status.